# A practical ice beam (freezing / encasing an object)

Tags: science-based

It's common to see "ice beams" that are able to freeze enemies or objects. Freezing a large object solid takes time, so most freeze rays aren't practical or logical, especially after factoring in differences in the material of the object.

As an alternate approach, is there a feasible way to snap-freeze water or another substance in a way that it freezes around an object? Is there a practical way to completely surround a human or other large object near instantly with a thick enough coating of ice/frozen material as to prevent movement?

Something such as a jet of a two liquids that chemically react and instantly crystallize, but without generating heat. I'm looking for something with an endothermic effect in particular, even if minor.

Hurdles to this question include variances in outside temperature (the effect should still be possible in Earthly temperature ranges, maybe 15C - 50C).

Comment: I think you'll find it's **much** easier to generate a quick-solidifying plastic foam of some sort than to generate a layer of ice.  do you want to kill the human or not?  encasing in anything solid will kill them due to lack of oxygen, regardless of temperature

Comment: I'm not sure that freezing beams are illogical, search for Laser Cooling. It is currently being used to remove the energy at the atomic level but advances are being made. [those guys](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2007/04/070406171036.htm) cooled 1 gram to almost the absolute zero, I couldn't find how long did it take though

Comment: did you mean F? 115C is above boiling...

Comment: Not sure how I typed 115C. Thanks for the catch.

Comment: Laser cooling could work small scale, but large scale I have no idea what it would take. Maybe someday we'll find a way to simultaneous remove heat energy from all atoms in an object and they laugh at us for saying it's impossible.

Comment: [Real-life video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hs0lpWN_SoI)

Comment: It's easy once you write the question to google it. "is there a feasible way to snap-freeze water"... hit #2 is *How to* [*Supercool*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercooling) *Water: 11 Steps (with Pictures) - wikiHow* (just trying to 'teach you how to fish')

Comment: Snap-freezing water requires a specific set of variables. It's not something you could weaponize, especially for the purposes of an ice beam.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Liquid nitrogen + liquid water**

Well, actually just about any liquid gas will work here, the best thing to use is liquid helium. Probably. Very little is known about how exactly liquid helium works due to how hard it is to get that stuff. You wanted to be able to encase something in ice. Well, this launcher has the perfect two step process to do it. Step 1: Spray with water to soak it. Step 2: Spray with liquid nitrogen. Now, liquid nitrogen is a minimum of -196 Celsius, but if you want you can do even better - you can take it to around -216 Celsius before it becomes a solid. Now, since liquid nitrogen is that cold, it will draw all the heat from the water it comes into contact with and instantly turn it into ice. Along with anything else it touches.

True, it'll produce a colossal amount of nitrogen gas during the process, but if you keep it pressurized and have a thick enough stream of liquid, you'll retain enough cold to freeze the water that you've already fired. This will, of course, result in the demise of whatever organics that come into contact with the water then nitrogen as they're flash frozen and sustain irreversible damage, so be careful not to point it anything you don't want destroyed.

Comment: How much nitrogen gas are we talking here, assuming the "beam" is large enough to coat a human-sized object? Is it enough that it could become an encumbrance for the firer?

Comment: @dinorider Liquid nitrogen, not gas. I wouldn't say that the liquid itself would be particularly cumbersome, but the equipment needed to contain it is. Think something akin to a WWII-era flamethrower for scale.

Comment: Ah, in your comments I thought you meant that the reaction would produce a giant smokescreen of nitrogen gas.

Comment: @dinorider Yes, that too. But only as a side effect.

Comment: ANd as a bonus, no body disposal needed. When it thaws out, it is freeze-dried powder, blowing in the wind, with just a slight tap.

Comment: Would it take a high enough pressure to overcome the Leidenfrost effect or would it just freeze because it's a thin layer of water? I imagine this would produce a very thin layer of ice on the object; what types of damage would the object incur?

Comment: @dinorider The water would help with the Leidenfrost effect as the water wouldn't turn to gas. You would still have to overcome the nitrogen/water Leidenfrost, but since you're spraying the nitrogen at the water, that will help with it. As for damage, it's hard to say. Mostly depends on the length of time, but exposure to liquid nitrogen typically results in freezing until brittle and permanent tissue damage. You might be able to take a very brief amount with only frostbite to show for it.

Comment: I would suggest using some sort of semi-frozen slush rather than liquid water. It's a little harder to store, but you can get much thicker coverage.

Comment: @Ruadhan It seems like that's the best bet, seeing as how it may freeze faster too.

Answer (score 13):

**Supercooled water.**

[image: supercools]

[source](https://www.bing.com/images/search?view=detailV2&ccid=1zZKQgXs&id=2DCF533ED174DCBB633AB54BB80D0847ED252628&thid=OIP.1zZKQgXsRZjrWMWTVbkCVwHaFj&mediaurl=https%3a%2f%2fi.ytimg.com%2fvi%2fOCRnmBGl-BE%2fhqdefault.jpg&exph=360&expw=480&q=supercooled+water&simid=608006157208912128&selectedIndex=3&ajaxhist=0)

This is water that is cooled past the point of freezing.  If anything happens to it, it turns to ice but until then it is water.  It is kind of like the guy in that Poe story who gets hypnotized when he dies, so he is tricked into still being alive.  Ok, just kind of.

In any case, shoot this out of a hose and it will turn to ice when it hits your target.  It is not exactly like comic freeze rays which in addition to freezing make big blocks of ice come out of nowhere.  But this stuff will hit you and wrap you in ice just fine.

Comment: Would the agitation from firing the water in a jet be enough to force the water to freeze on itself? And could the efficacy of the water freezing be affected by the ambient outdoor temperature?

Comment: @dinorider IIRC you need an impurity or seed point for the crystallization into ice to begin. It's like the diet Coke + Mentos reaction, but with ice instead of foam.

Comment: Funny, though in practice shock can be sufficient to start the freezing process. It could **realistically** work in a static setup, like a trap, for example above a door, would be triggered when the person passes under or tries to pick the lock. It's show on https://youtu.be/ph8xusY3GTM?t=134 then jump to the beginning of the video for explanation and to the end to see how it is finicky in practice.

Comment: Supper cooled water produces a slush due to the latent heat of freezing some of the water bringing the rest of the water up to the transition temperature. You'd have to get the liquid water to -80 C to  before it was cold enough to fully crystalize without having some liquid left. However the coldest you can theoretically get liquid water without it spontaneously crystallization is -49C, and practical concerns will raise this limit further. So this will produce a slush, not a solid.

Comment: My intuition is that you would need a completely laminar flow for this to not freeze in the hose.

Comment: [Supercooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercooling)

Comment: The water's temperature most likely is going to change if you're firing it at a target, and the turbulence of firing it at an object will most liekly create slush as @Rick stated.

Answer (score 5):

## Liquid nitrogen

Liquid nitrogen is very cold. Enough of it will kill you. Dunking something in liquid nitrogen makes it [very brittle](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9AYpRMvcBP8). As [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l1XRspReAvI) shows, a small amount won't do much (*don't try at home*). If you could first cover your target in water and then cover it in enough liquid nitrogen, you could create a freeze ray. A basic fire engine [like this](https://www.e-one.com/product/commercial-pumper/) can move around 2000 gallons of water per minute. Even with a much smaller pump, you could still wet and freeze your targets quickly.